# Check if element is clicked before removal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery code:

```
$(document).on('focusout', '#element_a', function(e){
     $('#element_b').remove();
});
$(document).on('click', '#element_b', function(e){
     // do other stuff here
});
```

So basically, I want to remove `#element_b` on focusout BUT if it's clicked, execute the click function before removal. The problem is that focusout executes before the click so by the time the click is registered, the element is already removed, so the click doesn't register and does nothing.

Comment: I think you need to change the strategy to _remove_ the element.

Comment: Just write down code inside focus out  that you need in click on #element_b . no need to write click of #element_b

Comment: You could add a delay to the `remove()` code.... but how long is practical? Agree that this strategy is a bit weak

Comment: What do you mean it's clicked? You actualy thinking if it's toggled on, active or? If you insist on being clicked. You can make onclick event handler that stores the fact that something is clicked in a variable by eg. setting it to true then when removing check if that variable is true;

Comment: Surely you can only focus out if it is clicked (so why not just do all your stuff in the onclick)?  Unless you are wanting to remove it if someone tabs over it and then off it? Also, what has `element_a` got to do with it or is that a typo.  If you mean that you want to run the focus out of a to remove b, how do you expect them to also click b when it has been removed, unless they click b before they even enter anything in a?

Comment: @Pete can't do it on click only because i want it either on focusout do something and on click do something and some other thing. So i must have both events

Comment: Is b always going to be clicked onfocusout?  If so then why not  click it in your focus out function before you remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing more about this UI the only thing we have to work with is what is shown. There may be better ways to accomplish your needs but based on what little is known you could add a `setTimeout` to delay the removal. Also add a class in the click event handler that the removal code checks for

```
var delay = 500;// adjust according to preference. Can even set it to zero

$(document).on('focusout', '#element_a', function(e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // only remove if it doesn't have selected class
    $('#element_b').not('.selected').remove();
  }, delay);
});
$(document).on('click', '#element_b', function(e) {
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  // do other stuff here
});
```

Comment: I think this is the most suitable and least hacky trick to do :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to remove element a or b. Just Trigger click event and then remove the element.

```
$(document).on('focusout', '#element_a', function(e){
     $('#element_b').trigger('click');
});
$(document).on('click', '#element_b', function(e){
     // do other stuff before remove element
     $('#element_b').remove();

});
```

Comment: This is leading user to do something they may not have intended. Suppose they intend clicking on `element_c` instead as the blur from `element_a`?

Comment: Not clear what you want to say above. Please elaborate.

Comment: OP wants to know if next event after blur on element a is click on element b. It may not be. This is an event sequence problem

Comment: Then he need to add classes to check item is clicked or not. If item is not clicked then he will remove it. As you suggested in your answer.

Answer (score -2):

The **[DEMO](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=238f9d936245dee692955b25f89798fd)** is here

You better use mouseleave instead of focus out.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#click').click(function(){
    alert('im clicked');
  });
  $('#click').mouseleave(function(){
    alert('im focus out');
  });
});
```

Comment: You also have misunderstood the event sequence problem